# How to use pdf-lib in Angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I found [this pdf-lib library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-lib?activeTab=readme#motivation) that I want to use in my angular project but I couldn't find any docs on how to import it in angular and I don't know the procedure of achieving this.

Can someone please help with me with importing this library (or any other npm library in general) to an angular project

Angular Version: 13.0.0

Comment: have you come to a solution

Answer (score 0):

`npm install pdf-lib` from your project root. The TypeScript types are included.